# PDO bindValue no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

(soy nuevo en PDO) La misma query si no uso bindValue funciona (puedo hacer fetch de las filas) pero al usar bindValue NO da ningun mensaje de error (ni el bindValue, ni el execute) pero el fetch no recupera ningún dato.

Ambiente: Windows 10 - WAMP 64 - MYSQL 5.7.36 - PHP 7.4.26

array $aDbLinks: Propiedad de la clase, cada elemento de este array es un array conteniendo todo lo relacionado con la conexion PDO.

string $ParDbSelector: es el selector del array $aDbLinks para seleccionar la data de 1 conexion en particular.

En los ejemplos, luego de establecer exitosaqmente $oLink al conectar con la db lo almaceno en:

```
             $this->aDbLinks[$ParDbSelector]['db_link'] = $oLink;
```

1. seteo atributos al establecer conexion para que try-catch funcione.

   ```
                $olink = new PDO(   $dsn, 
                                    $db_userLogin,
                                    $db_passLogin,
                                    array(  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE =>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', //after php5.3.6
                                            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
                                            PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                                         )   
                                );
   ```
2. Escribí una clase con primitivas para abstraer la E/S a la db.

   ```
        private function ejecuto_qry(    $ParDbSelector = APP_APLICACION,
                                $cQry, 
                                $aParams = ''
                            )    {
    $RetVal = false;

    // Valido parametros
    if ( $this->ExisteConexion($ParDbSelector) )
    {

        if ( $lTransaccion = ( 'SELECT' != $this->decodificoInstrucionSQL( $cQry ) ) )
        {
            $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['db_link']->beginTransaction();
        }

        try { 

            // Prueba para NO usar ->bindValue
                foreach ($aParams as $key => $value) 
                {
                    $cQry = str_ireplace($key, $value, $cQry);
                }
                $aParams = '';
            // fin Prueba para NO usar ->bindValue

            // Preparo la instruccion
            $stmt = $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['db_link']->prepare( $cQry,
                                    array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL) )
            or TerminoError('['.__FILE__.']('.__LINE__.') Fallo: ('.$stmt->errorCode().') ' );

            // Verifico parametros Vs cQry
            $lQryValida = true;

            // Proceso parametros 
            if ( is_array($aParams) and count( $aParams) )
            {   
                foreach ($aParams as $cNombreVar => $valor) 
                {
                    echo ' hago bind de: '. $valor.CR;

                    // verifico que cada  $cNombreVar esté en la $cQry
                    $nPos1 = stripos( $cQry, $cNombreVar );
                    if ($nPos1 === false) 
                    {
                        TerminoError( $cNombreVar.' no encontrado en $cQry = '.$cQry );
                        $lQryValida = false;
                        break;
                    }       

                    echo '['.__FILE__.']('.__LINE__.') reemplazo '.$cNombreVar.' = '.$valor.' del tipo: '.gettype($valor).CR; 

                    echo  '$stmt->bindValue('.$cNombreVar.', '.$valor.', PDO::PARAM_STR)'.CR; 

                    switch ( gettype($valor) )
                    {
                        case 'integer':
                            $stmt->bindValue( $cNombreVar , $valor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            break;

                        case 'string':
                            echo 'es string.'.CR;

                            $stmt->bindValue( $cNombreVar , $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR)
                                or TerminoError('['.__FILE__.']('.__LINE__.') Fallo: ('.$stmt->errorCode().') ');

                            break;

                        case 'bool':
                            $stmt->bindValue( $cNombreVar , $valor, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
                            break;

                        default:
                            TerminoError( 'Tipo de dato '.gettype($valor).'no soportado');
                            break;
                    }
                }   // foreach ($aParams as $cNombreVar => $valor)
                $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['params'] = $aParams;
            }  
            else
            {
                unset( $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['params']);
            } // Fin if ( is_array($aParams) )

            $lQryValida or TerminoError('['.__FILE__.']('.__LINE__.') cQry inválida. Revisar concordancia $aParams con $cQry');

            $stmt->execute( ) or TerminoError('['.__FILE__.']('.__LINE__.') Fallo PDO::execute de cQry ='.$cQry );

            $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['sql'] = $cQry;
            $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['stmt'] = $stmt;

            $this->CalculoFilasAfectados($ParDbSelector);

            if ( $lTransaccion )
                $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['db_link']->commit() ;

            $cRetVal = $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ];

        }
        catch (\Throwable $th) 
        {
        if ( $lTransaccion )
            $this->aDbLinks[ $ParDbSelector ]['db_link']->rollBack() ;
        echo "Transaccion anulada. Error: " . $th->getMessage();
        }
    }   // fin if ( $this->ExisteConexion($ParDbSelector) )
    return($cRetVal);}   }
   ```
3. Si dejo la parte de prueba,(reemplqazo a mano las variables del $cQry y blanqueo arreglo $aParams) el fetch trae las filas, pero si lo saco (par que el programa entre en el foreach de los bindValue, no salta ningun error, $stmt sigue siendo un objeto, pero el fetch no trae ninguna fila.

   ```
            // Prueba para NO usar ->bindValue
                foreach ($aParams as $key => $value) 
                {
                    $cQry = str_ireplace($key, $value, $cQry);
                }
                $aParams = '';
            // fin Prueba para NO usar ->bindValue
   ```

¿que puedo revisar?
desde ya muchas gracias.

Gustavo

Comment: Luego del ->execute al realizar el  ->debugDumpParams()
Reporta: (quite la sentencia porque era demasiado larga, la reemplace por ...)

 ==========debugDumpParams() ==============


SQL: [1259]  SELECT...AND t4.id_aplicacion = t11.id_aplicacion;
Params:  1
Key: Name: [12] :cAplicacion
paramno=-1
name=[12] ":cAplicacion"
is_param=1
param_type=2

========================

Comment: Hola. Sugiero que nos indiques exactamente cuál es el bloque que no funciona. Puedes explicar el contexto verbalmente y luego poner el código como lo tienes, de seguido, sin interrumpirlo con explicaciones y luego nos dices *no funciona en tal parte*. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta. Y no uses el área de comentarios para aportar cosas de la pregunta, es mejor ponerlo en la redacción de la pregunta. Los comentarios son para responder a quienes te comenten, si es que fuera preciso hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Cenado, gracias por responder. No falla ninguna sentencia, solo que el fetch no trae ningun registro si se ejecuta los bindValue.
SI reemplazo :cAplicación a mano antes del prepare y evito el bindValue el fetch trae las filas correctamente.

Comment: ¿En qué parte ocurre eso exactamente? Al poner el código en trozos es complicado analizar. Nosotros no somos tú, no tenemos en la cabeza la lógica de lo que intentas hacer ni hemos escrito ese programa, necesitamos ver el bloque completo para ver lo que ocurre. Las explicaciones que das no sobran, lo que he sugerido es que por un lado expliques verbalmente el contexto y lo que intentas hacer y que por otro lado nos muestres el bloque de código completo para revisarlo, no por trozos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ah, gracias. Escribi una clase que resuelva los accesos a la db usando PDO.
El método ejecuto_qry luego de prepaqrar la query, realiza un foreach del arreglo de paramnetros primero verificando que cada parámetro sea encontrado en la query y luego realiza el bindValue. 
Luego del foreach  hago un execute para luego devolver un vector con todos lo de ese query.  el problema es que luego el $stmt->fetch no trae ninguna fila. Si en cambio evito los bindValue reemplazando las variables en la query a mano antes del prepare luego el fetch trae las filas. Nunca da error.ejecuta bien

Answer (score 0):

encontré el error, estaba en la sentencia sql. La variable :cAplicacion originalmente estaba entre comillas. Las quité dejando la sentencia sql que paso como parámetro al prepare (como muestro a continuación.) Y el bindValue agrega comillas simples automáticamente en el momento que hace el enlace. (comprobado a través del comando PDOStatement::debugDumpParams que muestra la sentencia SQL con el valor ya reemplazado encerrado entre comillas simples. Abrazo y nuevamente muchas gracias

```
    $cQry = ' SELECT
          t11.id_empresa AS empresa_id,
          t11.id_sistema AS sistema_id,
          t11.id_aplicacion AS aplicacion_id,
          t11.id AS id,
          t11.valor,
          t12.id AS id_parametro,
          t12.codigo AS nombre_parametro
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              t1.id AS id_empresa,
              t1.codigo AS codigo_empresa,
              t2.id AS id_sistema,
              t2.codigo AS codigo_sistema,
              t3.id AS id_aplicacion,
              t3.codigo AS codigo_aplicacion
            FROM
              sgap_empresas AS t1
              INNER JOIN sgap_sistemas AS t2
                ON t1.id = t2.id_empresa
              INNER JOIN sgap_aplicaciones AS t3
                ON t2.id = t3.id_sistema
            WHERE
              t3.codigo = :cAplicacion ) AS t4,              
  sgap_valores_aplicaciones_parametros AS t11
    INNER JOIN sgap_parametros AS t12
      ON t11.id_parametro = t12.id
  WHERE
          t4.id_empresa = t11.id_empresa 
      AND t4.id_sistema = t11.id_sistema 
      AND t4.id_aplicacion = t11.id_aplicacion;';
```